# WebImage Crop After Resize dont work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, webimage

I upload a file , after upload base on info i got , i resize image , crop and resize it again

but just first resize work , crop and second resize do noting on image, after first resize what i must to do ?

```
  WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
  img.Resize(image_sw, image_sh);

  img.Crop(image_y, image_x, image_y + image_h, image_x + image_w);

  img.Resize(300, 300);

  var path = Request.MapPath("~/Content/images/category/" + model.ID + "." + type);
  img.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.resize%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method has a return argument with the new resized image. Just saving the img will save the old image in the old sizes.

Try this:

```
img = img.Resize(300, 300);
```